# Pointwise + Uniform Convergence:

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $(f_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be the seq. of functions $f_{n} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f_n(x) = \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\right)^{2n},~~~~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

> Find the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ and does it converge uniformly.

So my thoughts were to do as how I would normally would do so, but with a certain limit of it all i.e sub in $x=0$ etc.

We have no limit here so I go to the second method -
If i take the absolute value of $|f_n|$ and realise that $|\sin(x)| \leq 1 $ and then use it I just get

$$-1 \leq f_n(x) \leq 1$$

Which doesn't get me anywhere so I was hoping someone could help with this question thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds $\sin(\frac x \pi) = \pm 1$ if and only if $x= \pi(\frac \pi 2+ k\pi)$, for $k\in \mathbb Z$.
So for $x_0= \pi(\frac \pi 2+ k\pi)$ you got
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sin \left(\dfrac {x_0} \pi \right)\right)^{2n}=
\lim_{n\to \infty} (\pm 1)^{2n}=1.$$
For the other values of $x$ it holds $-1<\sin \left(\dfrac {x} \pi \right)<1$, hence $u:=\sin \left(\dfrac {x} \pi \right)^2\in[0,1)$. Therefore
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sin \left(\dfrac {x} \pi \right)\right)^{2n}=
\lim_{n\to \infty} (u)^{n}=0.$$

The sequence converges pointwise to the discontinuous function
$$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R\,, 
f(x)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1& \text{ if } x\in \frac{\pi^2} 2+ \pi^2\mathbb Z\\
0& \text{ else.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Since all the function $f_n$'s are continuous, but the limit $f$ is not, the convergence is not uniform.